# How to get Textfield value to show on desired position on screen

Tags: javascript, html

I need my text field value to be shown on another part of the screen when change text is clicked. How can I do this?

```
<div id="placetextfield">
  <script>
    var textfield = "Enter text on shirt:"; 
    textfield = textfield.bold()
    textfield = textfield.fontsize(5)
    document.write("<p>"  + textfield.fontcolor("#FF6600") + "</p>");
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2(){
      var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      document.getElementById('textfield').innerHTML = userInput;
    }
  </script>

  <b id='textfield'></b>
  <input type='text' id='userInput'/>
  <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()'value='Change Text'/>
</div>
```

Comment: is it not working now

Comment: i checked it is working now

Comment: what is the question here

Comment: like say i enter a name, i want that name to be shown somewhere (my desired location) on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('yourId').innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>
<b id='textfield'></b>
<input type='text' id='userInput'/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()'value='Change Text'/>
```

Comment: I  have tried this, This is my id 

#altext{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:50px;
}

substiting ('yourId') with ('altext')

it doesn't show the textfield value again